# How to replace the baseadapter value and how to stop the pagination loading in android filter screen?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, fragment, baseadapter

I have worked with the concept of filter that have to filter the job from job list based on skills and some list or there.

https://postimg.org/image/g3p1z6lbd/ - DashBoard Fragment.

About DashBoardFragment:

- Contains job list view.
- Dash Filter Button. - which redirect to the Filter screen.

  public class DashBoardRefactor extends Fragment {

  ```
  public static ProgressDialog progress;
  public static List<DashListModel> dashRowList1 = new ArrayList<DashListModel>();
  public static View footerView;
  // @Bind(R.id.dashListView)
  public static ListView dashListView;
  int preCount = 2, scroll_Inc = 10, lastCount;
  boolean flag = true;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment, container, false);
      ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
      setHasOptionsMenu(true);
      progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
      dashListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.dashListView);
      footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.dashboard_list_footer, null, false);
      dashListView.addFooterView(footerView);
      footerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      dashRowList1.clear();
      dashboardViewTask();

      dashListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              Log.d("onItemClick", "onItemClick <---- ");
              Intent toPositionDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), PositionDetailScreenRefactor.class);
              toPositionDetail.putExtra("id", dashRowList1.get(position).getDashId());
              startActivity(toPositionDetail);
              getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_left_in, R.anim.trans_left_out);
          }
      });
      final int totalJobCount = SessionStores.gettotalJobList(getActivity());
      Log.e("totalJobCount", "totalJobCount----" + totalJobCount);
      dashListView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(getActivity(), dashListView, footerView));
      return v;
  }

  public void dashboardViewTask() {
      progress.setMessage("Please Wait. It is Loading..job orders....");
      progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
      progress.setCancelable(false);
      progress.show();
      //    footerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      Log.e("candidate_id", "candidate_id---->" + SessionStores.getBullHornId(getActivity()));
      params.put("candidate_id", SessionStores.getBullHornId(getActivity()));
      params.put("page", "1");
      new DashBoardTask(getActivity(), params, dashListView, footerView);
      //  progress.dismiss();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
          Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      if (menu != null) {
          menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_notify);
      }

      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_options, menu);
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter);
      item.setVisible(true);
      getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle item selection
      switch (item.getItemId()) {

          case R.id.his__menu_accept:
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked dashboard  menu accept", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              return true;
          case R.id.menu_filter:
              // click evnt for filter
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked dashboard  filter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              Intent filter_intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DashBoardFilterScreen.class);

              startActivity(filter_intent);
              getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_left_in, R.anim.trans_left_out);

              return true;
          default:
              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  }

  public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      // dashboardViewTask();
  }}
  ```

### DashBoardTask:

```
                 public class DashBoardTask {
                     public DashBoardTask(Context context, Map<String, String> params, ListView dashListView, View footerView) {
                            this.context = context;
                            Log.e("context ", "DashBoardTask: " + context);
                            this.dashListView = dashListView;
                            this.params = params;
                            this.footerView = footerView;
                    ResponseTask();

                        }
                    private void ResponseTask() {
                    new ServerResponse(ApiClass.getApiUrl(Constants.DASHBOARD_VIEW)).getJSONObjectfromURL(ServerResponse.RequestType.POST, params, authorizationKey, context, "", new VolleyResponseListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String message) {
                            if (DashBoardRefactor.progress.isShowing()) {
                                DashBoardRefactor.progress.dismiss();
                            }
                           }
             @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
        //Getting Response and Assign into model Class
     int currentPosition = dashListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                            dashListAdapter = new DashListAdapter(context, DashBoardRefactor.dashRowList1, dashListView);
                            dashListView.setAdapter(dashListAdapter);
                            ((BaseAdapter) dashListAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

                            if (currentPosition != 0) {
                                // Setting new scroll position
                                dashListView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
                            }
                            if (footerView.isShown()) {
                                footerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                            //progress.dismiss();
                            if (DashBoardRefactor.progress.isShowing()) {
                                try {
                                    DashBoardRefactor.progress.dismiss();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
            }


DashListAdapter:
________________

    public class DashListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      public static ListView dashListView;
        Context c;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<DashListModel> dashRowList;
 public DashListAdapter(Context c, List<DashListModel> dashRowList, ListView dashListView) {
        this.c = c;
        this.dashListView = dashListView;
        this.dashRowList = dashRowList;
    }
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return this.dashRowList.size();
    }
 @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dashRowList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder dashHolder;
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_jobdetails_list, null);

        Log.e("get pos", "get pooooossss---->" + dashRowList.get(position));
        final DashListModel dashModel = dashRowList.get(position);
        dashHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
//Assign the value into screen 
  dashHolder.dash_company_name.setText(dashModel.getDashCompanyName());

    }
```

the above code for displaying dashboard fragment list.

https://postimg.org/image/nqvp1dud9/  - This link is FilterScreen

By using this image if i filter the job based on the designed UI detail. **That should replace into the DashboadFragment list**  The result should display into the DashBoard Fragment. How can I add pagination on Filter screen the same which have in DashBoardFragment.

Comment: without the code you tried we can't help

Comment: Editing please wait sorry. @Ak

Comment: Please review now now i have added the code. @AkshayBhat'AB'